# How to find IP address in line and append it to the end of line - with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need a sed solution for below file modification:
I have a text file containing an IP address in each line. I need to copy the IP address (along with some other text) to the end of the line:

before:

```
SOMETEXT <IP address>
```

after:

```
SOMETEXT <IP address> TEXT1 <IP address> TEXT2
```

I can separately add text to the end of line with

```
sed -e 's/$/ TEXT1 /' -i filename
```

and I can also get the IPs from the lines with

```
sed -n 's/.*\(\(\(^\| \)[0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{1\}\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{2\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\) .*/\1/gp' filename
```

Simply I just cannot compile this two together. :)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it, can you provide an example?

Comment: With awk: `awk '{print $0,"TEXT1",$NF,"TEXT2"}' file`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your expression is working (AKA: I didn't tried it myself):

```
sed -n 's/\(\(\(^\| \)[0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{1\}\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{2\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\) .*/\1 TEST1 \1 TEXT2/gp' filename
```

Comment: There may have been a small typo in this line, had to add .* after s/:
sed -n 's/.*\(\(\(^\| \)[0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{1\}\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{2\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\) .*/\1 TEST1 \1 TEXT2/gp' filename

However it only writes out the things that should be added to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){$0=$0 " TEXT1 " substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) " TEXT2"} 1' Input_file
```

OR adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)
{
  $0=$0 " TEXT1 " substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) " TEXT2"
}
1' Input_file
```

Comment: It does what I needed, nice one. Thanks!

Comment: @Szati, you could up-vote answers which you think helped you, you could try to select an answer as correct one out of any answers too.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}[.]\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\)/\1 TEXT1 \1 TEXT2/' in
```